# Filter an Observable array to return one result

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and angularfire2. In my service, I have an Observable array and I want to filter it to return just one result. Inside of all documents, there is a map called `moderatorAssigned` with an id property, this id is the `uid` of the user in firebase.

I have companies, each company has offices and an office has a moderator assigned and I would like to return to my component the office that the user had been assigned.

```
export interface Company {
  name: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  typeOfService: string;
  offices: Office[];
}

export interface CompanyId extends Company {
  id: string;
}

export interface Office {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  moderatorAssigned: {
    firstName: string;
    id: string;
    lastName: string;
  };
}
```

Component

```
export class SeeTurnsComponent implements OnInit {

  officeAssigned: Observable<Office>;

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService,
              private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const userId = this.authService.getUserUid();
    this.officeAssigned = this.companyService.getOfficeAssigned(userId);
  }

}
```

Template

```
<div *ngIf="officeAssigned | async as office">
    {{office.id}}
  </div>
```

Service

```
private companiesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Company>;
companies: Observable<CompanyId[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.companiesCollection = afs.collection<Company>(
      config.collection_companies,
      ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    );

    this.companies = this.companiesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Company;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return {id, ...data};
      }))
    );
  }

getOfficeAssigned(userId: string): Observable<Office> {
    this.companies.pipe(
      map(companies => companies.filter(company => {
        company.offices.filter(office => {
          console.log('comparing...');
          if (office.moderatorAssigned && office.moderatorAssigned.id === userId) {
            console.log('office found...');
            return office;
          } else {
            console.log('no office assigned...');
            return of(null);
          }
        });
      }))
    );

    return of(null);
  }
```

There is no data as a result, maybe I am doing something wrong.

My goal is, search inside of `companies: Observable<CompanyId[]>` in my service and return the office that the user has been assigned to show the data in the template.

Comment: In your filter function remove if condition and just add `return office.moderatorAssigned && office.moderatorAssigned.id === userId`.

Comment: Hi @randomSoul, thanks for answering me. Is not working for me. I did `office => {
          return office.moderatorAssigned.id === userId;
        }` but the return is `null`. Any idea?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues in your code:

```
getOfficeAssigned(userId: string): Observable<Office> {
    this.companies.pipe(
      map(companies => companies.filter(company => {
        company.offices.filter(office => {
          console.log('comparing...');
          if (office.moderatorAssigned && office.moderatorAssigned.id === userId) {
            console.log('office found...');
            return office;
          } else {
            console.log('no office assigned...');
            return of(null);
          }
        });
      }))
    );

    return of(null);
}
```

First, your method always returns `of(null)`. That makes no sense. You want to return an Observable obtained by transforming `this.companies`.

The code should thus look like:

```
getOfficeAssigned(userId: string): Observable<Office> {
    return this.companies.pipe(
      map(companies => this.findOfficeWithAssignedUserId(companies, userId))
    );
}
```

Then implement the `findCompanyWithAssignedUserId` method, and test it. Note that it doesn't need to use any Observable-related type or method. It only needs to `find` an element of that array. It should look like

```
findOfficeWithAssignedUserId(companies: Array<Company>, userId: string): Office {
    const company = companies.find(c => 
      c.offices.some(office =>
        office.moderatorAssigned.id === userId
      )
    );
    return company && company.offices.find(office =>
      office.moderatorAssigned.id === userId
    );
}
```

The code would be better with flatMap, but flatMap is still experimental. There are other ways, more efficient, to make that loop, but this should be fast enough and give you the idea.

Comment: I would use  `.reduce()` to replace the `.map()` and the `.find()`. because using those 2 methods means iterating through the array twice.

Comment: Err, no. map() here is an observable operator. It transforms an Observable<Array<Company>> into an Observable<Company>. It doesn't iterate anything.

Comment: maybe I'm getting confused, I could be wrong  but according to the rxjs documentation it says "apply projection with each value from source" which it iterates

Comment: Yes. That means that every time the observable emits a new array of companies, this new array is transformed into the company in this new array that contains the user ID.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, thanks for help me. Right now I'm receiving an error in the `getOfficeAssigned` method. `Type 'Observable<Company>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Office>'.   Type 'Company' is not assignable to type 'Office'.     Property 'id' is missing in type 'Company'.`. There is a way to return an `Office` and not the entire `Company`?. If not, it's okay, I think I can change the type of the `Observable` in the component.

Comment: but you can transformed it with `.reduce()` too right?

Comment: we can just chat about it ( idk want to confuse the OP) I want to learn your point of view :)

Comment: @PatricioVargas reduce is used to accumulate all the emitted events, once the observable completes, into a final unique value. The Observable never completes here.

Comment: @JBNizet In my case, a company can have multiple offices but, a user only can be assigned to just one office, that's why I would like to receive in my component just the office that I belongs to, to receive updates constantly about changes on that office especifically.

Comment: @JBNizet I saw your update, thanks for trying but, I am receiving two errors. In the first method: `Type 'Observable<Company>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Office>'` and in the second method: `Type 'Office' is not assignable to type 'Company'.   Property 'createdAt' is missing in type 'Office'`.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. But really, you should be able to understand these errors and fix the code by yourself. If you don't understand the code I posted, then by all means don't use it. Use it only once you understand every single line of it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with with the logic that you used and either with Observables yet. I'm debbuging your code with logs in console to see what is happening behind, as you said, my goal is to learn too and learn more ways to do stuff. Thanks for all your help and your advice, I really appreciate it. Just to mention, you have a misspelled word in the first method, `sompanies`. The code is working and I really want to thank you for your effort to explain my error.

Comment: The only part that I don't understand completely is the `return` in the `findOfficeWithAssignedUserId` method, `return company && company.offices.fin......`, you are returning a logic that I don't get it. Can you add some explanation in your answer please?. I hope is not too much to ask.

Comment: This is a somewhat weird (but common) construct in JavaScript/TypeScript. It's basically equivalent to `if (company) { return company.find(...)); } { else return company; }. If the first operand (`company`) is falsy (i.e. undefined here), then the AND can only be falsy, and the company (which is undefined) is returned. If the company is truthy, then the the second operand is evaluated and returned.

Comment: It's also often used with `||`: `return a || b` returns `a` if `a` is truthy, and returns `b` otherwise.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. Something that came up right now, if the user hasn't any office assigned, I receive an error in console: `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. I tried to do a condition inside of `findOfficeWithAssignedUserId` to check if `office.moderatorAssigned.id === userId` is true, otherwise return `null` to show a message to the user in the template. My tries were bad, do you have any idea about how can I make sure if there is any office assigned or return a `null` correctly or something?.

Comment: I am doing `*ngIf="officeAssigned | async as office; else noOfficeAssigned"` and it's working to show a message to the user in the template but, I'm trying to not get errors in console, maybe I am being too picky?